# Send request in applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, swift, url, request, xcode8

In my app I need to send some instructions to server when the user terminated an app. In applicationWillTerminate func I tried to send it, but it never came to server. I tried to use Alamofire and native URLSession but it doesn't work. Does anybody know how can I send it?
I use this code

```
                let request = "\(requestPrefix)setDriverOrderStatus"
    if let url = URL(string:request) {
        var parameters : [String : String] = [:]
        parameters["access_token"] = UserSession.accessToken
        parameters["driver_id"] = UserSession.userID
        parameters["status"] = status
        var req = URLRequest(url: url)
        req.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.put.rawValue
        do {
            req.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "error")
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        }).resume
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad method to try and contact your server; you have limited execution time and it won't always be called. You should reconsider whether you need to call on application termination, or whether application entering the background is sufficient. If you do want to use `applicationWillTerminate` then you need to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`

Comment: my app can work in background, I checked when app in background background task begins

Answer (score 15):

One solution that worked for me is to add sleep at the end of the `applicationWillTerminate` function like this :

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

    // HERE YOU will make you HTTP request asynchronously
    self.postLogoutHistory()

    // 3 is the number of seconds in which you estimate your request 
    // will be finished before system terminate the app process

    sleep(3)

    print("applicationWillTerminate")

    // self.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: This works, although that approach seems good only for quick test purposes (I needed this for quick test, not production app). For proper implementation it should be probably done using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`as @Paulw11 mentioned in above comment (but I didn't test it, so can't tell if it really works).

Answer (score 0):

put `breakpoint` in `applicationWillTerminate` and check that, function is getting called or not because `applicationWillTerminate` is not called everytime when application is getting terminated, especially when user quit application manually from multitasking window, `applicationWillTerminate` will not get called! When system terminates the application at that time `applicationWillTerminate` will get called and you will got approximately five seconds to complete your task!! So, it is not good idea to perform network related task on `applicationWillTerminate`!!

Refer [Apple Documentation for applicationWillTerminate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate), It states,

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any
>   final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources,
>   saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this
>   method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return.
>   If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill
>   the process altogether.
>
> For apps that do not support background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user
>   quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method
>   is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app
>   simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may
>   be called in situations where the app is running in the background
>   (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.
>
> After calling this method, the app also posts a
>   UIApplicationWillTerminate notification to give interested objects a
>   chance to respond to the transition.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate is getting called and my function is done, but request doesn't come to server

Comment: it is possible that five seconds is not enough to complete your network request! Or your code may also some issue you can say! But it is not recommended to make network request on `applicationWillTerminate` because it is not guarantee that your network request will be completed in 5 seconds! It's vary on internet speed also!

Comment: the request is very simple I need only one second to get response, completionHandler never works

Comment: then you are making some mistake in making network request and handling response of it! There are many kind of possibilities for that! Without seeing code no one can say that what is mistake! and once you should try to execute same code in another method other then `applicationWillTerminate`!

Comment: I add the code to question, In foreground it works perfectly

Comment: If it is working in foreground that means you are not getting sufficient time to perform your task in `applicationWillTerminate`!!